# using empty with php SESSION - 0 case

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Good Morning! I have a variable "var" which maybe 0. I check if the variable is null and if it is not I save this variable in a php session and i call another page. In this new page I check if the session I've created is empty or not, but when it is 0 it returns that the session is empty. It does not sound so crazy! But even if I use

```
if($_SESSION['SESS_NUM']!=NULL)
```

it stil can;t see the 0 number as 0. Is there any way to check the 0? The content of the variable "var" comes from an sql query(the function with the sql query returns

```
$f_result[thenum];
```

Comment: Please format your question for better readability (one empty line before code) or use backticks for inline code. To your problem: Do a strict check with `$_SESSION[SESS_NUM'] === 0` to be completetely sure it is definitely a 0. PHP is kinda tricky with comparisons, because sometimes it converts things internally and sometimes not. Or: are you sure you're opening your `session_start()` everytime? Can you dump your session with `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: Actually I want to check the session variable so if it is null to redirect the user in another page. But if it zero or any other number to do something else. So I used this line if(empty($_SESSION['SESS_NUM']) || !$_SESSION['SESS_NUM']===0) maybe there is something wrong in it. It does not work. I used the isset that @Sudhir suggest and it is working. Thank you!

Comment: @anna if your question is solved by Sudhir, could you please select that as the answer? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_NUM'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['SESS_NUM']; //if 0 shows 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IDENTICAL comparsion operator `===` (http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It checks if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

```
$_SESSION['SESS_NUM0'] = 0;

if($_SESSION['SESS_NUM0'] === 0) {
// Checks if $_SESSION['SESS_NUM0'] IS (int)0
  var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_NUM0']); // prints int(0)
}
```